# Having trouble with a node.js app on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am trying to create a simple node.js app on heroku. Here is app.js:

```js
console.log("Starting App")

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`))

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html')
})

app.get('/style', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/main.css')
})

app.get('/script', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/script.js')
})

app.get('/changelog', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/changelog.txt')
})
```

here is my package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "/App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

and here is my Procfile:

```
web: node app.js
```

I am deploying this to heroku via github, and whenever I run the program it gives me an error, saying Cannot find module '/app/app.js' can anyone help me with this?

Edit: I have made everything lowercase and I still get this error: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'

Comment: @ change "main": "/App.js" to "main": "app.js" because they are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

First, the name of the app is case sensitive - you use app.js in your description, and App.js in your package.json. They should be consistent, and the convention is lowercase.

Second, you don't need the forward slash.

Comment: What's your folder structure? Why is it looking under "/app/app.js"? If the main server file is in a folder called app, try switching your main to: "main": "app/app.js". You don't need the forward slash.

Comment: app.js is in the root directory

Comment: Have you removed the forward slash "/"?